# How can I split a combined row of data in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```sql
SELECT
        t1.pay_id,
        t1.order_no,
        t1.payer_member_id agent_id,
        t1.business_amount,
        t1.pay_status,
        t2.goods_name,
        t2.quantity,
        t2.array_skus,
        dateadd ( HOUR, 1, t1.update_time ) update_time,
        t5.order_no refund_order_no,
        t5.status refund_status,
        t5.refund_count,
        t5.refund_type,
        dateadd ( HOUR, 1, t5.create_time ) refund_create_time,
        dateadd ( HOUR, 1, t5.update_time ) AS refund_update_time
    from report_mongo.ng_t_pay_flow_dms t1 
    left join report_mongo.ng_t_merchant_order_goods t2 on t1.order_no =t2.order_no 
    LEFT JOIN  report_mongo.ng_t_refund_order T5 on t2.order_no=t5.pre_order_no
    WHERE t1.trans_type='u0'
```

the result show is:

[image]

I want to split them, but I failed

[image]

Comment: You can't be using Postgres if that query works for you.

Comment: why ，there are Skuid and SkuName in my list

Comment: dateadd() is not a standard PostgreSQL function. Maybe you created one.

Comment: To me that looks a result set in some client language, say Javascript or Python. Is that the case? If so you will need to unpack the array/list and the contained object/dict. In other words you need to provide more information about how the query is being made and where the results are being returned. **ADD that information as update to question**.